# find a particular function in a executable using dumpbin tools family

Tags: assembly, disassembly

Is it possible to know with dumpbin tools if a executable under windows use the command arp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really. If it has `arp.exe` as a string literal, and passes that string literal to `WinExec`, `CreateProcess`, etc., that'll be pretty easy to find. It could, however, do something like reading `arp.exe` in from a file at run-time, which will make it considerably more difficult to find.

Comment: Try "Strings" tool by Mark Russinovich: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439